# Generate proxy class for selected web methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, wsdl

I have a real big (exposing nearly 200 webmethods) asp.net web service. I am developing a second application which consumes very few webmethods of this service (2 webmethods). When I generate proxy class of 1st web service using visual studio, it is generating it for all web methods. Is there any way we could generate proxy class for selected web methods and the custom types used only in those web methods.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible. However, the classic workaround for this is to use a facade pattern, exposing to your application only those methods that are of interest, and delegating directly to the real web service methods.

For example:

```
public interface IWebServiceWrapper
{
    void DoStuffWith(Something something);

    SomethingElse GetSomeThingElse(int id);

}


public class ServiceWrapper : IWebServiceWrapper
{
    private TheRealWebService _realWebService = new TheRealWebService();

    public void DoStuffWith(Something something)
    {
        _realWebService.DoStuffWith(something);
    }

    public SomethingElse GetSomeThingElse(int id)
    {
        _realWebService.GetSomeThingElse(id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to do it manually.

It is still pretty easy to maintain, but of course more manual effort than using the automatic generation. Also disposing can be added in a good way.

```
public class ServiceProxy : ClientBase<IService>, IService>, IDisposable
{
  public Response DoAction(Request request)
  {
    return Channel.DoAction(request);
  }

  private bool disposed;

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if (!this.disposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (base.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
            {
                this.Abort();
            }
            else if (base.State != CommunicationState.Closed)
            {
                try
                {
                    this.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    this.Abort();
                }
            } 
            disposed = true;
        }
    }       
}
```